# Can't upgrade - error "/etc/environment: source: not found" and "error processing package install-info"

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

This is the error message I get when I do a sudo apt upgrade. The upgrade fails and includes this message:

```
Setting up install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: source: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I reinstalled install-info through synaptic and am still getting this error and would be grateful for help in setting me straight as to how to read this message and
 how to react..

Comment: Can someone help me to read this error message? It seems to be saying /etc/environment is missing something? It's simply a line of path statements.

Comment: Looking at the error, it seems there is a command in the script `/usr/sbin/update-info-dir` that says `source /etc/environment`, but it is being run by a shell (dash I guess) that doesn't know the `source` command. Instead of `source`, that script should have `. /etc/environment`, which does the same thing. That's very very strange. [Here's the version of that file I have on my system](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/C3RKtBm9y8/)

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069702/dpkg-error-processing-package-install-info

Answer (score 1):

I found this way down in a thread elsewhere, and it worked!

> if all else fails. What I did was I first changed the directory to:
>
> ```
> cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
> ```
>
> then I removed everything with `.postinst`:
>
> ```
> sudo rm *.postinst
> ```
>
> then update repositories
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> then everything went back to normal when I did:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get --force-yes install openjdk-7-jre-headless
> ```

Note: I did not do this last line, as my issue didn't have anything to do with openjdk. I simply ran the `apt update`

Comment: Another option is to edit the offending `.postinst` file and put `exit 0` on the second line (after the first line containing `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I started to get same thing and just used

```
for i in $(ls -F *.postinst); do mv ./$i ./$i.old; done in /var/lib/dpkg/info
```

then my standard ansible playbooks to bring servers current worked

Comment: those files will have standard names, but in general, [you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and more importantly, you shouldn't post answers with commands with no explanation of what they do! Please [edit] this to add some commentary